# Pinvoke vs ManagedCode

Tags: c#, .net, c++, pinvoke

I was wondering which is better translating a C++ code to C# or Pinvoking it from C# app

which would be better in terms of performance and memory and other

Answer (score 5):

If you are running on Windows the third option (the one missing from your list) is best. Leave the code in C++ and compile it with C++/CLI. Then your C# code can consume it directly without need for P/invoke or translation.

Comment: tyvm this is gonna help me alot ;)

Answer (score 0):

[There's a good description of how to do this on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky8kkddw%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: tyvm this is gonna help me alot